# Finding first of consecutive dates using analytical functions

Tags: oracle, plsql, data-analysis

I need to analyze a piece of data stored in one Oracle database table. The example rows in this table is like this:

```
Department  Date    Status
------------------------------------
D1          2016/6/1    1
D1          2016/5/31   0
D1          2016/5/30   0
D1          2016/5/29   1
D1          2016/5/28   0
D1          2016/5/27   1
D2          2016/6/1    0
D2          2016/5/31   1
D2          2016/5/30   1
D2          2016/5/29   0
D2          2016/5/28   0
D2          2016/5/27   1
```

There is one row for each department and each date. What I want is, for each department for ANY GIVEN DATE, find the first date when the `Status` is 0 prior to this date. For example, for department D1, for 2016/6/1, the result is 2015/5/30, and for D1, 2016/5/31 and 5/30 it is also 2015/5/30. For D1, 2016/5/29 and 5/28, it is 2016/5/28.

I need to output the result as a `SELECT` result and store it in another table. So the result table has exactly the same number of rows as the original table. There is probably three columns in the result table: `Department`, `Date`, `TargetDate`.

I have little experience in SQL / PL SQL. I guess I should use analytical function and windowing, but I really can't come up with the query. Please give me some advice. Thank you!

Comment: Analytical function is right (and windowing), but first please clarify the requirement. What is the desired result for D2 and 2016/5/27? That is, what if the oldest row for a department has status 1 (or more generally, different from zero)? .... and actually wait, you said when status is 0 but then in your example for D1 and dates 5/29 and 5/28 you say the result should be 5/27, but 5/27 has status 1, not 0. Please clarify. (Preferably by editing your post, not in comments.)

Comment: @mathguy Thank you for your comment. 1) If the oldest row has status 1, or different from zero, the `TargetDate` should be null meaning we can't find any date prior to that date with status 0. 2) Sorry. For D1 and 5/29, 5/28, the result should be 2016/5/28. That was a typo. I already corrected it in the original post.

Comment: Cool, thanks. One more question just to make sure I understand the requirement. It seems for each date, you go to the most recent date when the status was zero (perhaps the date itself if it has status zero, or go back in the history till you find the first zero). Then DON'T select the most recent date with status zero; rather, if it's part of a sequence of consecutive days with status zero, select the oldest date from that consecutive sequence. That is why the answer for 6/1, 5/31 and 5/30 is 5/30 for department D1. Right? If so, this is an application of the so-called "tabibitosan" method.

Comment: @mathguy you understanding is absolutely correct (to find a first/oldest date of a block of consecutive dates whose status are all 0. And the block itself is closed and prior to the given date. The status on the given date can be either 1 or 0) . Since you already named the method clearly (and I found the article on Oracle community), I'll try to understand that myself. If I still can't figure it out, I'll come back to you. Thank you very much!

Comment: I was wrong; the tabibitosan method won't help in this case, but the analytical function `lag()` will (in addition to whatever else I had in mind). Posting it as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with test_data (department, date_, status) as (
       select 'D1', date '2016-06-01', 1 from dual union all
       select 'D1', date '2016-05-31', 0 from dual union all
       select 'D1', date '2016-05-30', 0 from dual union all
       select 'D1', date '2016-05-29', 1 from dual union all
       select 'D1', date '2016-05-28', 0 from dual union all
       select 'D1', date '2016-05-27', 1 from dual union all
       select 'D2', date '2016-06-01', 0 from dual union all
       select 'D2', date '2016-05-31', 1 from dual union all
       select 'D2', date '2016-05-30', 1 from dual union all
       select 'D2', date '2016-05-29', 0 from dual union all
       select 'D2', date '2016-05-28', 0 from dual union all
       select 'D2', date '2016-05-27', 1 from dual
     ),
     t (department, date_, status, lagged_status) as (
       select department, date_, status,
              lag(status) over (partition by department order by date_)
       from   test_data
     ) 
select   department, date_, 
         max(case when status = 0 and (lagged_status = 1 or lagged_status is null) 
                  then date_ end)
             over (partition by department order by date_
                   rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as target_date
from     t
order by department, date_ desc
;
```

Result:

```
DEPARTMENT  DATE_      TARGET_DATE
----------- ---------- -----------
D1          2016-06-01 2016-05-30
D1          2016-05-31 2016-05-30
D1          2016-05-30 2016-05-30
D1          2016-05-29 2016-05-28
D1          2016-05-28 2016-05-28
D1          2016-05-27 (null)
D2          2016-06-01 2016-06-01
D2          2016-05-31 2016-05-28
D2          2016-05-30 2016-05-28
D2          2016-05-29 2016-05-28
D2          2016-05-28 2016-05-28
D2          2016-05-27 (null)

12 rows selected.
```

Please note, "date" is an Oracle keyword and shouldn't be used as a column name; I used date_ instead (I added an underscore).

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. Thank you very much!